# Initializing a dictionary in kotlin

Tags: file, kotlin, dictionary, hashmap

How can I complete this code so I can initialize a dictionary in Kotlin with some words I wrote in another file?

val fisier= File("src/main/resources/Poveste_dictionar.txt")
val Dictionar = hashMapOf<String, String>(.........)

the file looks like that:
Once"                to  "Odata",
"upon"                to  "ca",
"a"                   to  "",
"time"                to  "niciodata",
"there"               to  "acolo",
"was"                 to  "a fost",
"an"                  to  "o",
"old"                 to  "batrana",
"woman"               to  "femeie",

Comment: what's the format of your input file? Have you tried any code so far?

Comment: What do you mean by the format of the input file? it has strings and I mentioned how the file looks..I don't know if the code I wrote is partially correct or it needs to be totally changed but I just want to know how to read data from a file and put it directly into a dictionary using HashMapOf

Comment: does the file look like `"Once" to "Odata", "upon" to "ca"` and so on? So all pairs are separated by a comma + a space, and each individual word is wrapped in quotes and the pair is separated by a `to`? And also is everything on one line?

Comment: Yes, that is correct except that they are not on the same line.  There is a line for every 2 words

Comment: first line: "Once" to "Odata" ; second line:  "upon" to "ca" and so on

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file looks like this:

```
"Once" to "Odata"
"upon" to "ca"
"time" to "niciodata"
```

you can use the following code to create a map that contains all associations:

```
val fileContent = this::class.java.getResource("dictionary.txt")?.readText() ?: throw FileNotFoundException() // read the file or throw exception if it doesn't exist
val words = fileContent
    .lines() // iterate over each line
    .associate { line ->
        val (first, second) = line.split(" to ") // extract the first and second word
        first.removeSurrounding("\"") to second.removeSurrounding("\"") // remove quotes and create a Pair
    }

println(words)
```

That snippet produces the following output:

```
{Once=Odata, upon=ca, time=niciodata}
```